# TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox gives error "Module is not a valid type"

Tags: vb6

I am trying to empty all controls on my VB6 form through this code

```
Public Sub ClearControls(frmName As Form, TagName As String)
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In frmName.Controls
If ctl.Tag = TagName Then

If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
ctl.Text = ""
ElseIf TypeOf ctl Is ListView Then
ctl.ListItems.Clear
ElseIf TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox Then
ctl.Clear
ElseIf TypeOf ctl Is OptionButton Then
ctl.Value = False
ElseIf TypeOf ctl Is DTPicker Then
ctl.Value = Date
ElseIf TypeOf ctl Is Label Then
ctl.Caption = ""
ElseIf TypeOf ctl Is CheckBox Then
ctl.Value = 0
End If

End If
Next
End Sub
```

it is giving me following error when it checks for Combobox and Listview

"A Module is not a valid type"

any suggestions?

Comment: What is the name of the module that this code site in?

Comment: error comes when it checks for combo box or listview

Comment: Certainly - but the code you show is in some kind of class, form, or module - what is the name of that class, form, or module?

Comment: Also, if you've asked questions previously and have gotten responses, make sure to mark the helpful responses as answers. This will help you get more help in the future.

Comment: This is a public function written in a module named as GModule, and i am calling this function from a form named as frmemp, and passing paramaters from form. i have debugged the code and when debugger reaches on line where it is checking for "is listview" it generates error. sorry if i could not explain the question very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a code module (class, form, .BAS file, usercontrol) called `ComboBox` or `ListView`?

Try qualifying the name fully so that it isn't ambiguous

```
ElseIf TypeOf ctl Is VB.ComboBox Then
```

And I suggest you untick "Compile on demand" in the VB6 options, as it's much better to be told about compile errors immediately, rather than when code execution reaches the problem line.

Comment: Great! Please "accept" the answer by clicking on the transparent tick to the left of my answer. The tick should go green.

Comment: @user1115284: Also feel free to +1 this answer by hitting the gray triangle pointing up to the left of the answer.